# SSRS (MS Report Builder) - How do I add multiple lines of queried details to a single row of otherwise more general info?

Tags: reporting-services

I've been trying to figure this out, but I'm struggling.

Working in Microsoft Report Builder (latest version), I have a table that, for the most part, contains general information from a specific table, which I'll call GeneralInfo.  In that table, each person has only a single row containing information about that person.  However, one of my columns has a one-to-many relationship with the rest of the row.  I'll call this other column DetailInfo.

This table provides an example of the kind of thing I'm going for:

[image: Example Table]

In this example, all of the white cells come from the GeneralInfo table.  The Orange cell may include many rows of work history, and each entry includes multiple elements from the DetailInfo table, separated by Newlines.  The two tables can be matched / joined on the ID value.

This may not be the best way to go about a report, but it's part of the spec I was given.  I know this can be done, but I'm having trouble learning *how.*  Can anyone help me out?

**Edit** - I just found out that another column is also potentially one-to-many.  In the example table, it would be saying that the "Occupation" value comes from the DetailInfo table, rather than the GeneralInfo table.

In MOST circumstances, this would just be "Construction Foreman" over and over again, and we would only want to show that once.  However, in rare circumstances, an individual may have multiple concurrent (differing) Occupation values that would have to be shown.  Is that possible?  Should I make that a separate question?

Comment: the best way to do this is in your datasource. If SQL is your back end.. then use something like String_agg for later versions of SQL or stuff for XML to put multiple lines into a single line and then display it on the report. show some reproducible sample data and we could help you further

Comment: Try to create a Sub-Report with parameter passed with ID. And call that sub report into work history column. pass the main report's ID value to sub report's parameter.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to respond, we've been having some DB issues.  The Sub-Report option seems the best way to go; thanks for the assist!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took Soundappan A's advice and created a sub-report in the column that needed the extra data.  This video was helpful to me in learning how to set that up:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LhSitVAnhyc